# Limit $ \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}{\sqrt{x}-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$ \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}{\sqrt{x}-1}$

How would I solve this limit question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: let $z = x^{1/6}$

Comment: Use formula $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{x^{n} - a^{n}}{x - a} = na^{n - 1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **METHODOLOGY $1$:**  L'Hospital's Rule

L'Hospital's rule works efficiently here.  We have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{x^{1/3}-1}{x^{1/2}-1}\right)&=\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{\frac13x^{-2/3}}{\frac12 x^{-1/2}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac23\end{align}$$

---

> **METHODOLOGY $2$:**  Non-Calculus Based

Alternatively, for those unfamiliar with differential calculus, we can simply write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{x^{1/3}-1}{x^{1/2}-1}\right)&=\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{\frac{x^{1/3}-1}{x-1}}{\frac{x^{1/2}-1}{x-1}}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{x^{1/2}+1}{x^{2/3}+x^{1/3}+1}\right)\\\\
&=\frac23
\end{align}$$

Comment: Your explanation is always the best. Could you possibly show how to solve it by let $x=t^6$ as other people have commented?

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.  Letting $x=t^6$, we have $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{1/3}-1}{x^{1/2}-1}=\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{t^2-1}{t^3-1}=\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{t+1}{t^2+t+1}=\frac23$$

Answer (score 3):

Try change of variable $x = t^6$.

Answer (score 2):

Setting $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$, we can rewrite the limit as 
$$ \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}{x-1}\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}-1}=\frac{f^{\prime}(1)}{g^{\prime}(1)}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: for the sake of context, one might mention Hopital's rule, the use of which you are demonstrating 'by hand'.

Answer (score 0):

*Another possible way to do it.*

Define $x=1+y$ which makes $$A=\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}-1}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+y}-1}{\sqrt{1+y}-1}$$ and use the generalized binomial theorem or Taylor series which write $$(1+y)^a=1+a y+\frac{1}{2} a(a-1)  y^2+O\left(y^3\right)$$ which then gives $$A=\frac{1+\frac{y}{3}-\frac{y^2}{9}+O\left(y^3\right)-1 } {1+\frac{y}{2}-\frac{y^2}{8}+O\left(y^3\right)-1 }=\frac{\frac{y}{3}-\frac{y^2}{9}+O\left(y^3\right) }{\frac{y}{2}-\frac{y^2}{8}+O\left(y^3\right) }=\frac{\frac{1}{3}-\frac{y}{9}+O\left(y^2\right)} {\frac{1}{2}-\frac{y}{8}+O\left(y^2\right) }$$ Now, using long division $$A=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{y}{18}+O\left(y^2\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Making the problem more general, consider $$B=\frac{\sqrt[p]{x}-1}{\sqrt[q]{x}-1}$$ and the same procedure would give $$B=\frac{q}{p}+\frac{ (q-p)}{2 p^2}y+O\left(y^2\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=t^2$. Then this is the definition of the derivative of $t^{\frac 23}$ at $1$